# Change color of shape in xml drawable file through layout

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-custom-view

So I created this drawable xml file called rounded_rect. I initially set its color to red. However I want to be able to change this color in my layout file.

rounded_rect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#ffff1900"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>

<stroke android:width="4dp"
    android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

My layout file contains a custom View called ItemView. One of my custom attributes is background color.

```
<custonview.android.example.com.customview.ItemView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:imagePath="@drawable/yes"
    custom:text="Yes"

    custom:backgroundColor="#000000"

    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_green"
    android:layout_margin="30dp" />
```

The goal is to be able to change the color in my drawable file to the color I assigned in my layout file. Here is my ItemView.java file

```
public class ItemView extends View {

    //attributes of item view
    private Drawable drawable;
    private String text;
    private int backgroundColor;

    private int width, height;
    private Paint paint;

    public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ItemView, 0, 0);
        try {
            text = a.getString(R.styleable.ItemView_text);
            backgroundColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ItemView_backgroundColor, 0);
            drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.ItemView_imagePath);
        } finally {

        }
        paint = new Paint();
        width = drawable.getMinimumWidth() / 2;
        height = drawable.getMinimumHeight() / 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //positions the image in the middle horizontally and a little above the text below
        drawable.setBounds(width / 4, height / 4 - 50, width - (width / 4),
                height - (height / 4) - 50);
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        paint.setTextSize(100);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(text, width / 2 -
                paint.measureText(text, 0, text.length()) / 2, height - 50, paint);
    }
}
```

- Maybe I am over contemplating it. Free free to be creative in your answers. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code-

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)yourview.getBackground();
        bgShape.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create separate drawables for each colour, as there is no way to set those attributes in runtime - because the application would have to compile them.